# Using django-registration with recaptcha on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, recaptcha, pip, django-registration

I'd like to try Django on Heroku.  I'd like user registration with recaptcha.

Heroku [recommends](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) using pip.  pip installs django-registration 0.7, since that's the latest released package. (0.8 has apparently been in alpha for 4 years?).  [django-recaptcha](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-recaptcha/0.0.3) requires django-registration 0.8.  When I pip install django-recaptcha, it tries to pip install django-registration, gets 0.7, and is sad.

What's the easiest thing to maintain?  Should I not use pip for these, download both tarballs and put them in my source tree?

I am surprised that user registration with captchas is not smooth in a framework that's been around as long as Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the requirements.txt file to take a specific version of the django-registration repo ("tip" is a good choice for django-registration at the moment):

Replace you the line in your requirements file which looks like this:

```
django-registration==0.7
```

with:

```
hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/@tip
```

Comment: Thanks! If the plugin works, I'd like to grab that version until I test a new one. So, I used hg+https: //bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/@fad7080fe769 (space for formatting here).  Read more at http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html.